# Can't update from 19.04 to 19.10

Tags: updates, sudo, 19.04, 19.10

```
sudo apt-get update
```

gives me this error:

```
Err:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu disco Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
```

I don't know if this is related but sudo in general also gives me this error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/security/howdy/compare.py", line 17, in <module>
    import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
Unknown error: 1
```

Comment: You might want to try disabling that 3rd party PPA before running the upgrade.  The actual upgrade command is `do-release-upgrade`, but then again, that command should disable all 3rd party PPAs before install.

Comment: If my answer is helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark and up-arrow icons just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: status please...

Answer (score 1):

http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu is a very old repo, and their last release was for bionic (not disco).

You can do no wrong by opening `Software & Updates`, and deleting that PPA.